# Resolution of the singularities of the curve $X^2Y^2 + Y^2Z^2 + X^2Z^2=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, curves

> **Problem:** Let $C=\{[X,Y,Z] \in \mathbb{P^2}\mathbb{C} \mid X^2Y^2 + Y^2Z^2 + X^2Z^2=0\}$.
>
> Resolve the singularities in $C$.

**Tried so far:** Since the polynomial is symmetric in the three variables, we can suppose wlog $Z=1$. Computing the derivatives we find out that the point $P=[0,0,1]$ is the only singularity on the curve of this kind, and thus there are 3 singularities, namely $P$, $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$. We need to study $P$. The curve on the affine plane takes the form $x^2y^2 + y^2 + x^2=0$ with a singularity in the origin $(0,0)$. We attempt a blow up! Should we try $(x,y)=(u,uv)$ and $(x,y)=(uv,u)$ or just one of them? We try out the first one. We get $u^4v^2 + u^2v^2 + u^2=0$. Since $u$ is not $0$ (why??) we get $u^2v^2 + v^2 + 1=0$. Setting $u=0$ (we just said $u$ is not $0$!!! ... ???) we find two possible values for $v$ and thus the singularity should be a node. (are there any other possibilities?) We did it! There are 3 nodes on $C$. Is there a way to write down the equation for the curve with the singularities resolved?

Thanks!

Comment: No question that there’s three nodes in the original. You want an equation in the plane? There’s no reason why it should be nonsingular in the plane, seems to me.

Comment: @Lubin Probably I wrote that down in a bad way. Let's say we have a curve with one singularity. We perform a blow-up in order to obtain almost the same curve but with no singularities. Is there a way to write down the equation of the new nonsingular curve obtained this way?

Comment: @Lubin I mean, which is the point in the question "Resolve the singularities"? Enumerate and describe all the singularities? That's all we can do?

Comment: This is just the part of algebraic geometry where my knowledge weakest (and most out of date), I fear. But once you have every point nonsingular, you can do things like analysis of the group of divisors modulo principal divisors, for instance. Precisely what are the principal divisors, anyway? Is the desingularized curve irreducible? What’s its genus? Easiest to answer these questions when the curve is desingularized.

Comment: @Lubin I got it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you did all the computations necessary, only that you're a bit confused as to how to interpret what you did.

1) In the chart $(u,v)$ as you used in your answer, the equation $u=0$ cuts out the exceptional divisor (the fiber of the blow up over the origin). The equation $u^4v^2+u^2v^2+u^2=0$ is what you get when you pull back $C$ to the blow up.

However, as you see from the equation, this equation also contains the exceptional divisor (which makes sense, as the original curve passed through the origin). This is called the *total transform*.

However, we would like to remove these extraneous copies of the exceptional divisor. To do that, we divide the equation $u^4v^2+u^2v^2+u^2=0$ by as many copies of $u$ as possible. In this case, dividing by $u^2$ suffices, and we get the *proper transform* $u^2v^2+v^2+1=0$, which we can directly check is nonsingular.

2) Blowing up gives a recipe for desingularizing any plane curve. Any smooth curve can be mapped into $\mathbb{P}^2$ with only nodal singularities, but they cannot in general be embedded into $\mathbb{P}^2$, so it makes sense that blowing up doesn't give us an equation for the desingularized curve as a plane curve.

In our case, however, the arithmetic genus of a degree 4 curve is 3. Since there are three nodes, the genus of the desingularized curve is $3-3=0$. This means the desingularized curve is just a $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you tell me why the proper trasform is nonsingular? $(f_u,f_v)=(2uv^2,2u^2v+2v)$ can be $(0,0)$ in the origin and in several other points! Morover is that ok that $(0,0)$ is not a point on the proper trasform?

Comment: Certainly, $(f_u,f_v)$ can be $(0,0)$ , but, in order for the proper transform to be singular, we also need $f=0$. I don't see any better way to show this can't happen then to directly solve via casework. It is okay that $(0,0)$ is not on the proper transform; this will happen only if one of the branches of the original curve has slope 0 (whatever book you are using hopefully explains how blowing up separates branches near the blow up point by slopes).

Comment: Let's see if I got it! If $(0,v)$ is not a point of the proper transform for every $v$ I can ignore the whole chart because it tells me nothing about the singularity. If $(0,v)$ is a point of the proper transform I need to check that it is nonsingular on the proper transform. If some of them is singular I perform another blow up. At the end of the process if we get one point the singularity is a cuspide, if we get two points is a node. Is that right?

Comment: Sounds right. It's probably what you meant, but nodes and cusps can be resolved in a single blow up. As you say, if you can desingularize with a single blow up, and the curve intersects the exceptional divisor with multiplicity 2, then it's either a node or cusp. It's a node if it intersects at two distinct point and a cusp if it intersects at one point with multiplicity 2. A general singularity might require multiple blow ups, as you say.

Comment: Certainly $u^2 v^2 + v^2 + 1 = 0$ is a nonsingular affine curve, but this is really just an affine piece of the projective curve $U^2 V^2 + V^2 W^2 + W^4 = 0$ that is the blow-up of $C$.  This still has singularities at $[0:1:0]$ and $[1:0:0]$, so it seems to me that we have to blow it up twice more to resolve all the singularities.

Comment: I think you might be confusing affine charts covering the blowup with affine charts covering projective space.